# Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null, but jsfiddle working

Tags: javascript, html

This is the first time I've run into a situation like this...I'm running an `Apache` server in a `xampp` environment and I'm working on a login page, and I wanted to put a JavaScript button that shows the password when clicked. It's not working in my environment, but it is working on `jsfiddle`. I've supplied the code below:

```js
document.getElementById("eyeButton").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    'use strict';
    var pwd = document.getElementById("password");
    if (pwd.getAttribute("type") === "password") {
        pwd.setAttribute("type", "text");
    } else {
        pwd.setAttribute("type", "password");
    }
});
```

```html
<input 
       type="password" 
       id="password" 
       name="password" 
       maxlength="50" 
       placeholder="Enter password..." 
       required 
       pattern="(?=^.{8,}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W+)(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$"
       title="Password must contain at least eight characters and one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.">
        <button type="button" id="eyeButton">
            <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/eye-16.png" alt="eye">
        </button>
```

The `JavaScript` code is linked to the page correctly, so I don't know why I would be getting the `Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` error.

Comment: That's because JSFiddle runs the code when the DOM is finished loading. You have to manually do it

Comment: What does this have to do with php?

Comment: Or Apache/Xampp :-)

Comment: @theomessin I just supplied my entire stack I was working with, because I wasn't sure what parts could've been interacting with it

Comment: Apache or PHP will never dictate how Javascript is executed on the client, unless you use AJAX or stuff like that.

Comment: @Capsule OK, good to know. I'm still relatively new, so I wasn't completely sure.

Comment: To answer your question, when do you execute that script? It needs to be after the input, otherwise it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Notice that if you click "Run code snippet" your code works fine? Right-click on the working demo and click "View Frame Source" and you'll notice that it has been structured with the `<script>` element *after* the other elements. Do that in your real project too and it should be fine.